# Replace selected columns' negative values with 0s or NAs using R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, tidyverse

For the example data `df`, I want to replace the negative values in the first column (`x1`) with `0` and the third column (`x3`) with `NA` by the function `replace_negatives` as follows:

```
df  <- data.frame(x1 = -3:1,      
                    x2 = -1,
                    x3 = -2:2)
df
```

Out:

```
  x1 x2 x3
1 -3 -1 -2
2 -2 -1 -1
3 -1 -1  0
4  0 -1  1
5  1 -1  2
```

Please note that I do not index by column names because there are many columns in the actual data and the column names are not fixed.

```
replace_negatives <- function(data){
  df <<- data %>% 
    mutate(.[[1]] = if_else(.[[2]] < 0, 0, .[[1]])) %>%
    mutate(.[[3]] = if_else(.[[3]] < 0, NA, .[[3]])) 
  return(df)
}

lapply(df, replace_negatives)
```

But it raises an error:

```
> replace_negatives <- function(data){
+   df <<- data %>% 
+     mutate(.[[1]] = if_else(.[[2]] < 0, 0, .[[1]])) %>%
Error: unexpected '=' in:
"  df <<- data %>% 
    mutate(.[[1]] ="
>     mutate(.[[3]] = if_else(.[[3]] < 0, NA, .[[3]])) 
Error: unexpected '=' in "    mutate(.[[3]] ="
>   return(df)
Error: no function to return from, jumping to top level
> }
Error: unexpected '}' in "}"
```

Any helps would be appreciated.

The expected output:

```
  x1 x2 x3
1  0 -1 NA
2  0 -1 NA
3  0 -1  0
4  0 -1  1
5  1 -1  2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `across` in the function:

```
library(tidyverse)

replace_negatives <- function(data){
  df <- data %>%
    mutate(across(1, ~ ifelse(. < 0, 0, .)),
           across(3, ~ ifelse(. < 0, NA, .)))
  return(df)
}

replace_negatives(df)
```

**Output**

```
  x1 x2 x3
1  0 -1 NA
2  0 -1 NA
3  0 -1  0
4  0 -1  1
5  1 -1  2
```

Comment: If I want to replace negative values with 0s in both the first and second columns, at this case I should use: `across(c(1, 2), ~ ifelse(. < 0, 0, .))`?

Comment: @ahbon Yes, that is correct. `across` can take a number of different arguments, but for your purposes, it can take a vector with the column indices.

Answer (score 2):

To perform the required operation, here's a base R method:

```r
df  <- data.frame(x1 = -3:1,      
                  x2 = -1,
                  x3 = -2:2)

df[[1]] <- ifelse(df[[1]] < 0, 0, df[[1]])
df[[3]] <- ifelse(df[[3]] < 0, NA, df[[3]])

df
#>   x1 x2 x3
#> 1  0 -1 NA
#> 2  0 -1 NA
#> 3  0 -1  0
#> 4  0 -1  1
#> 5  1 -1  2
```

<sup>Created on 2022-04-18 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Here is base R version of your function:

```
replace_negatives <- function(df){
    is.na(df[,1]) <- df[,1] < 0
    index <- df[,3] < 0
    df[,3][index] <- 0
  return(df)
}


replace_negatives(df)
```

```
  x1 x2 x3
1 NA -1  0
2 NA -1  0
3 NA -1  0
4  0 -1  1
5  1 -1  2
```